# JSF selectItem label formatting

Tags: java, jsf

Trying to keep all the presentation stuff in the xhtml on this project and I need to format some values in a selectItem tag have a BigDecimal value and need to make it look like currency. Is there anyway to apply a `<f:convertNumber pattern="$#,##0.00"/>` Inside a `<f:selectItem>` tag?

Any way to do this or a work around that doesn't involve pushing this into the java code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research here I'm pretty convinced this isn't possible with the current implementation of JSF. There just isn't an opportunity to transform the value.

http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/selectItem.html

The tld shows the `itemLabel` property as being a `ValueExpression` and the body content of `<f:selectItem>` as being empty. So nothing is allowed to exist inside one of these tags, and the label has to point to a verbatim value in the Java model. So it has be be formatted coming out of the Java model.

Comment: again. i just noticed i had already answered to this exact same question months ago. SO is becoming my personal notepad.

Answer (score 2):

being a beginner to jsf i had a similar problem, maybe my solution is helpful, maybe its not in the "jsf spirit"

i just created a custom taglib and extended the class (in my case org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlCommandButton) and overrided the setters to apply custom parameters.

so instead of  `<t:commandButton/>` i used `<mytags:commandButton/>`, which is as flexible as i want.

Comment: That is actually completely in the JSF spirt. I'm trying to write as little code dependent on JSF as possible. Mostly just a lofty design goals but I think it makes our project clearner, more maintainable etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a converter with that pattern, but that sounds like the exact opposite to what you want.