# Formatting a double in JSF

Tags: jsf, formatting, decimal

I have a problem similar to the one found here : [JSF selectItem label formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86531/jsf-selectitem-label-formatting).

What I want to do is to accept a double as a value for my  and display it with two decimals. Can this be done in an easy way?

I've tried using  but that seems to be applied on the value from the inputText that is sent to the server and not on the initial value in the input field.

My code so far:

```
<h:inputText id="december" value="#{budgetMB.december}" onchange="setDirty()" styleClass="StandardBlack">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" groupingUsed="false" />
</h:inputText>
```

EDIT: The above code actually works. I was fooled by JDeveloper that didn't update the jsp page even when I did a explicit rebuild of my project and restarted the embedded OC4J server. However, after a reboot of my computer everything was fine.

Comment: Try using backticks (`) to surround JSF code which contains < and > characters - I think it's eaten some of your post!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding your requirement, I was able to achieve formatting of the value in the input box during the rendering of the view with:

```
<h:inputText id="text1" value="#{...}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###,##0.00"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I was using the Standard Faces Components in my vendor-branded Eclipse so I'm assuming the `pattern` attribute is part of standard JSF.

Comment: Your code worked with some changes to the pattern. However, I also found my own code worked now. JDeveloper didn't take the changes I did even when recompiling and restarting the embedded OC4J server. After a reboot of my computer everything worked fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is make the value of the input text field change on screen (to correct user input), you should probably look into using one of the JSF ajax frameworks like [Rich Faces](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/support.jsf?c=support&tab=usage).

A possible example would look like this:

```
<h:inputText id="december" value="#{budgetMB.december}" styleClass="StandardBlack">
  <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" groupingUsed="false" />
  <a4j:support event="onblur" reRender="december" />
</h:inputText>
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it may work.

Comment: Actually it was the other way around. I don't need to validate the input but format the default value of the input field. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're actually formatting a currency. There already exists a specific formatter to handle currencies that you can assign many options to:

```
<f:convertNumber type="currency" />
```

Some interesting attributes of this tag are: `locale`, `currencyCode`, `integerOnly`, `currencySymbol` and `pattern`.