# How format number and put in input

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have an input number and I must acept vlaue with 34,34 two decimal number so my code is:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
    <input type="number" min="0" name="price" pattern="0.00"
                        step=".01" required
                        value="<fmt:formatNumber type = "number" 
                        pattern="0.00" value = "${home.price}" />"
```

The problem is that the inpput is empty is not loaded the value, because if I do

```
<label><fmt:formatNumber type = "number" 
                    pattern="0.00" value = "${home.price}</label>
```

the number is printed in the correct form. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `var` attribute on `fmt:formatNumber` to store the outcome and use it in your input, and make sure you are using a locale which provides numbers which the browser can work with:

```html
<fmt:setLocale value="en"/>
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" 
                  pattern="0.00" value="${home.price}"
                  var="myNum"/>
<input type="number" min="0" name="price" pattern="0.00"
                    step=".01" required
                    value="${myNum}"/>
```

Especially the locale makes this quite ugly, so I really recommend to have a look at [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf).

See also:

- [Localization of input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412204/localization-of-input-type-number) (JSP)
- [JSTL formatNumber for JSP custom pattern independent from language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899343/jstl-formatnumber-for-jsp-custom-pattern-independent-from-language)
- [Formatting a double in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166897/formatting-a-double-in-jsf)